# ASP.NET MVC Template built in with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, templates

does anyone know awesome templates for Visual Studio integration. I have found some here http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/, but they are dead. I would like get the same for free or for money.
Thank you.

Comment: I would look at the site asp.net and would also wait MVC 4 which should be released soon and should contain plenty of new features and templates like better Mobile devices support etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here http://pixelsinspired.com/ is only one application template, but it looks that the rest is coming soon. Ready to go designer templates with CSS/HTML and basic application utils like logging and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you're building with ASP.NET, you could always use a basic HTML theme, and cut out the middle part, make a master page and views. If there's re-usable elements, break them down into partials.

Assuming you're not using some CMS software, you'll probably be needing to customize the views to match data coming from your controllers.

One of the advantages of ASP.NET MVC vs WebForms is that's much closer to other templating languages. It wouldn't be that bad to convert an `erb`,`twig` or `smarty` template to ASP.NET. I'm guessing that most of what you're really looking for is the markup and CSS.

Comment: I think Vladimir Gnenniy is talking about ready to go ASP.NET MVC template including ability of stylizing generated views with layout requirements.